# MVVM and nested view models

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a simple example where I'm creating a View consisting of a list box, and the list box displays a bunch of items. I'm wondering if I'm going about the creation of the View Model and Model classes correctly here. Use whatever value of correctly works in this context, I understand it's a bit subjective, but my current solution doesn't feel right. Here's a simplified version.

The ViewModels and Models:

```cs
namespace Example
{
  public class ParentViewModel
  {
      public ParentViewModel()
      {
          // ... Create/Consume ChildViewModel * n
      }

      public List<ChildViewModel> ChildViewModels { get; set; }
  }

  public class ChildViewModel
  {
      public ChildViewModel()
      {
          // ... Create/Consume ChildModel
      }

      public ChildModel Model { get; set; }
  }

  public class ParentModel
  {
      public List<ChildModel> ChildModels { get; set; }

      public ParentModel()
      {
          // ... Create/Consume ChildModel * n;
      }
  }

  public class ChildModel
  {
      public ChildModel()
      {
          // ... Contains actual data.
      }

      public string Data { get; set; }
  }    
}
```

The View:

```
<Window x:Class="Example.View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Example="clr-namespace:Example" Title="View" Height="300" Width="300"
    DataContext="{StaticResource TheViewModel}">
    <Window.Resources>
    <Example:ParentViewModel x:Key="TheViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="278" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels}"/>
</Grid>
```

In the proper code, the listbox will use a data template to display the child view models. But as you can see I'm not sure how the to instantiate the child related objects. It feels like the ParentViewModel will have a reference to the ParentModel and create ChildViewModel objects based on the ParentModel's ChildModel objects. Now I've said that it doesn't sound so daft, but I'd be interested in your thoughts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are on the right track.

The parent model would naturally contain a list of child models, e.g. a customer having multiple orders.

When `ParentViewModel` is created and loaded by a third-party, it is passed a `ParentModel`. Then the `ParentViewModel` will:

1. Assign the `ParentModel` to a local variable
2. Create a `ChildViewModel` for each `ChildModel` by passing the
   `ChildModel` to the `ChildViewModel` constructor
3. Add each of those `ChildViewModels` to a list

By the way, you want

```
public List<ChildViewModel> ChildViewModels { get; set; }
```

to be

```
public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> ChildViewModels { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't think the Model would hold a reference to the ViewModel, or really know about it at all. I assumed the View had a reference to the ViewModel, and the ViewModel had a reference to the Model. This could be me confusing MVC, MVP, MP, MVVM and the myriad other variations though :)

Comment: Sorry, NO! the model never holds a reference to ViewModel, always the other way around. Basically ViewModel knows about Model and no knowledge of View. View does not know about view model or model, only binding using property names.

Comment: Hah, thank god. It wouldn't be the first time I'd got everything back to front :)

Comment: You will get there, MVVM was one of the toughest challenges I had recently.

Comment: Heh yep, I have a load of tools in my bag to make it all work, it's really getting it to work in the least complex, easiest to maintain way possible and for that I need all your help and experience :)

Comment: Also note that the ViewModels may not directly reflect the Models at all. The VM is whatever the View needs to display. So if you're displaying an aggregate of the children, ParentViewModel may only expose that aggregate (e.g. count of children; sum of all orders; min and max of all receipt totals). Depends on what your view needs.

Comment: Also, should this: "it is passed to a ParentModel" be changed to this: "it is passed a ParentModel"?